# apache system-redirects.conf one domain to another

Tags: apache, redirect, dns

I want to configure my apache system-redirects.conf to redirect from:
www.example.com/mail -> www.example2.net/mail

So i want to have both domains, but i want that my co-workers access to only one webmail link.

I tried this:
Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/mail http://www.example2.net/mail

Didn't work, what am i doing wrong?
Thanks for the help.